# Derive many arrays from existing numpy array to calculate correlation coefficient

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given the following numpy array of hundreds of items:
[Ticker, currency, date, exchange rate]

```
array([['AIndex', 'AUD', '2018-01-01', 1.28],
       ['BIndex', 'EUR', '2018-01-01', -0.248],
       ['CIndex', 'HKD', '2018-01-01', -1.18],
       ...,
       ['DIndex', 'JPY', '2018-04-06', -1.046],
       ['EIndex', 'EUR', '2018-04-06', 1.092],
       ['Findex', 'CAD', '2018-04-06', 0.61]], dtype=object)
```

I would like to find which 2 tickers (i.e. AIndex, BIndex) have the strongest correlation given the rates at the end of each item (ex: 1.28).

I want to avoid creating a new array manually for each type of ticker, and the correlation needs to be done by date by ticker, ignoring the currency.

I would then be able to score the correlation coefficients and find the ones that are strongest using this method:

[How do you calculate correlation between all columns in a DataFrame and all columns in another DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932065/how-do-you-calculate-correlation-between-all-columns-in-a-dataframe-and-all-colu/28934228#28934228)